# API for city boundaries for drawing circles around search results in OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

We have a following case:

1. We have our own search filters which include some areas eg. cities, districts, bigger regions.
2. We extract that data and use it for query (e.g: `['Paris', 'Queens New York']`).
3. ... magic (?)
4. I receive center and furthest points in N/S/W/E directions so I can draw a circle over OSM map.

Is there any API that would do that? I believe `nominatim` used in OSM won't return wanted data.